# Unable to select alert message in SVG format in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, alert

I am using SVG file format for drawing graph.
And I hope some info pops up as an alert when I click a node.
Info would be same as tooltip.
So I wrote it as below.

```
<g id="a_node11502"><a xlink:title="Youtiao (Chinese Deep Fried Donuts)" href="#" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('xlink:title'))">
```

However, I found some weird thing.
When I put '&#10;' in string, It is now allowed to select text in alert box.
**But** Firefox allow it to selected. Therefore I think it is kind of weird thing in chrome. I know that '&#10;' is a newline character. Do you know how to solve this problem?

```
<g id="a_node11502"><a xlink:title="Youtiao (Chinese Deep Fried Donuts)&#10;" href="#" onclick="popup(this)">
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2HDe.png)

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You shouldn't rely on being able to select text in an alert box anyway.  Not all browsers allow this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to do what I did.

It seems post-processing is needed.

```
<a xlink:title="YAKULT is delicious" href="#" onclick="popup(this)">
<script>
function popup(e){
    alert(e.getAttribute('xlink:title'));
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.getAttribute('xlink:title'))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Text copied to clipboard');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // This can happen if the user denies clipboard permissions:
    console.error('Could not copy text: ', err);
  });


}
</script>
```